# asp.net text substring depend on the width of div

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a div with this style

```
{padding:5px;width:240px;height:auto;float:left;text-align:left;}
```

When i write text string in this div , a long text is wrap and enter to a new line .

[image]

I want to sub string this long text depend on the width of div (240px).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to div style

```
 text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

**Note:**
`text-overflow: ellipsis` property is supported in Internet Explorers 6 & 7, Safari 3 & 4, Chrome 1 &2, it requires special handling for IE 8 Standards Mode, Opera, and FireFox.
See [here for further browser support.](http://mattsnider.com/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Substring() method in c# code while displaying the categories menu.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the css property text-overflow=ellipsis to do this in the browser

```
<ul>
 <li style="text-wrap:ellipsis">really really really really really really long</li>
</ul>
```